# Numpy subset array between first and last occurence of logical expression match

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array, which is a vector (1 by n). I want to subset it between the first and last occurence of where it meets a boolean expression (greater than some number).

I.E. something along the lines of:

```
positions = numpy.where(myArray >= value)[0]
subset = myArray[positions[0]:positions[-1]+1]
```

This is one solution, but as I understand it, this will involve searching through the entire array twice to retrieve the `positions` result. `myArray` can be very large, so are there any other solutions?

Comment: Accessing the first and last element of the array does not involve any searching, it already knows where those elements are. This is pretty much the most efficient way you could do this. As far as i know at least.

Comment: As listed this will cutoff the last value for example if your array is `arr = np.array([0,1,2,0])` and cutoff is `1` do you want `np.array([1,2])` or `np.array([1])`?

Comment: @ M4rtini; `where` and boolean indexing do require searching.

Comment: @Ophion, yes I missed that. I adjusted the code - I want the full result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets list some methods:

```
def original(arr, val):
    pos = np.where(arr>=val)[0]
    return arr[pos[0]:pos[-1]+1]

def with_argmax(arr, val):
    pos = (arr>=val)
    return arr[pos.argmax():-pos[::-1].argmax() or None]
```

Setup with a medium sized array and few values to clip:

```
arr = np.ones(1E5)
arr[:300] = 0; arr[-300:]=0
```

Timings:

```
%timeit original(arr,1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 504 µs per loop

%timeit with_argmax(arr,1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 297 µs per loop
```

---

Same array size with more values to clip:

```
arr = np.ones(1E5)
arr[:2E4] = 0; arr[-2E4:]=0
```

Timings:

```
%timeit original(arr,1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 528 µs per loop

%timeit with_argmax(arr,1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 296 µs per loop
```

What you really want is a "find first nonzero element" routine which is not currently in numpy, but aimed for numpy 2.0. More info can be found [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2269).

Comment: Great answer. I will try this out and report back

Comment: @jramm Because searchsorted uses a binary search the results of an unsorted array are unpredictable. If this is not sufficiently fast I believe the best way to continue is likely to create some sort of chunk algorithm that iterates through parts of the array, if `chunk[chunk.argmax()]!=1` go to the next chunk else stop. This will prevent argmax from having to iterate through the entire array twice.

Comment: Thanks Ophion. The answer is great. Minor performance gains are not that desirable (so the your with_argmax code is fine) - the idea was to replace a generator expression with no loss in performance so that it could be 'cythonised'. That has all been achieved now!